# NFS vs. root filesystem, cannot access mounted subdirectories

Tags: linux, nfs

Slowly giving up on this...

I am trying to export root filesystem via NFS, but mounted `/usr/portage` subdirectory is empty or is mounted instead of `/`.

Details below.

Host:

```
mount | grep portage

/usr/portage.mount/portage.sfs on /usr/portage.mount/readonly type squashfs (ro,noatime)
unionfs on /usr/portage type fuse.unionfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other)
```

### First approach.

Host:

```
/etc/exports
/ *(sync,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
```

Guest:

```
mount -t nfs -o rw,noatime,nocto,actimeo=60,lookupcache=positive,vers=4,fsc 192.168.1.1:/ /mnt/192.168.1.1
ls -l /mnt/192.168.1.1/usr/portage
```

**Result = empty folder**

### Second approach.

Host:

```
/etc/exports
/usr/portage *(sync,rw,no_root_squash,subtree_check,nohide,fsid=0)
/ *(sync,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,crossmnt,nohide)
```

Guest:

```
mount -t nfs -o rw,noatime,nocto,actimeo=60,lookupcache=positive,vers=4,fsc 192.168.1.1:/ /mnt/192.168.1.1
ls -l /mnt/192.168.1.1
```

**Result: contents of /usr/portage from host system** (expected root filesystem with usr/portage mounted)

### Third approach.

Host:

```
mount -t bind / /media/root

/etc/exports
/media/root *(sync,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,crossmnt,nohide)
```

Guest:

```
mount -t nfs -o rw,noatime,nocto,actimeo=60,lookupcache=positive,vers=4,fsc 192.168.1.1:/media/root /mnt/192.168.1.1
ls /mnt/192.168.1.1
ls: cannot access 'media': Too many levels of symbolic links
```

---

What am I missing ?

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: How is `/mnt/192.168.1.1/usr/portage` containing "contents of `/usr/portage` from host system" when you list it, _not_ what you want?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Second approach: `ls -l /mnt/192.168.1.1/usr/portage` -> `ls -l /mnt/192.168.1.1`. Trying to list `/mnt/192.168.1.1` results in contents of `/usr/portage` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding fsid to both exports did the trick.

Host:

```
cat /etc/exports

/usr/portage *(sync,rw,no_root_squash,subtree_check,nohide,fsid=1)
/ *(sync,rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,crossmnt,nohide,fsid=0)
```